# Determing if the head of a circular doubly-linked list is part of a "jump" cycle

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

There's a doubly linked list which is also circled (i.e., the last node's `next` pointer points to the head of the list and the head's `prev` pointer points to the last node).

The `data` in each node is an integer.

A jump in a circular list is defined as follows for a node `p` :

- if `p.data` is positive, we move `p.data` times using the `next` pointer
- if `p.data` is negative, we move `p.data` times using the `prev` pointer
- if `p.data` is 0, we don't move at all.

I need to write a method that receives a pointer to the head of the list as a parameter and returns `true` if there's a jump path that starts and ends at the head node.

An example list:

```
 node | data | next | prev
------|------|------|------
   0  |   2  |   1  |   5
   1  |  14  |   2  |   0
   2  |  -5  |   3  |   1
   3  |   1  |   4  |   2
   4  |  -4  |   5  |   3
   5  |   1  |   0  |   4
```

For this list, the method should return `true`. Starting at the head (node 0), we move forward twice to node 2, then back 5 times to node 3, forward once to node 4, and finally back 4 times, returning to node 0:

```
 node  | jumps | next node
-------|-------|-----------
   0   |   2   |     2
   2   |  -5   |     3
   3   |   1   |     4
   4   |  -4   |     0
```

My main problem is when I should return `false`.

This is not homework (I'm working on different exercises in order to prepare my self for an exam)

Comment: Have you tried writing any actual code?

Comment: Yes i tried , but it makes me an infined loop , because i don't know how to stop it when there's no path

Comment: If you're working on exercises to prepare for an exam, I'd say you're doing your homework. That in itself is to be commended, but it's homework nonetheless. Part of the definition of homework reads: _"research or reading done in order to prepare for something"_ [source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do it.

For example you can return false if you didn't get back to the head after n jumps (n being the length of the list) as it means you are looping in another part of the list.

You can also mark the visited nodes and return false if you visit twice any node (apart from the head).

You also have to return false directly if you reach a 0 which is not the head of the list.

Comment: There can be a viable path that is longer than 'n'

Comment: I don't think there can be, as the next position depends only on current value. If you get twice to the same node you will go the same way again so you have a loop. So you can only go once per node, hence n is maximum without loop.

Comment: Yeah, after rethinking I conclude you're right and I was wrong. Counter should be enough.

Comment: @CMoi Yeah correct, if a node is visited twice then there is no feasible solution.

Answer (score -1):

First decide when the method will stop i.e. what is the halting condition as given your question above again the method will start moving and will return to 2 and this process will continue ever. The only halting condition specified above is the occurrence of zero in the zero otherwise this program will never halt.

If coming to the head node can also result in halting of the program then the code can be completed in this way:

```
findHead(head,originalHead,calledCount){
    if(originalHead==null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (head==originalHead && calledCount>1) 
    /*If while roaming gets to the head then returns true but except the first time where the head will always be equal to original head */
    {                   
        return true;
    }
    else {
        p=head;
        if(p.data>0)
        {
            steps=p.data;
            while(steps>0)
            {
                p=p->next;
                steps--;
            }
            findHead(p,originalHead,calledCount);
        }
        else if(p.data<0)
        {
            steps=p.data;
            while(steps<0)
            {
                p=p->prev;
                steps++;
            }
            findHead(p,originalHead,calledCount);
        }
        else    // If obtained 0 in the list
        {
            if (p==originalHead)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    calledCount++;
}
```

Comment: The only halting condition is not landing on a 0 node. As the accepted answer points out, after you visited all of the nodes, it is safe to stop. So that's one halting condition (the other is, of course, finding a cycle earlier).